# JUnit ServiceTest for getAll method which contains Pageable, Page object and stream()

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am new to Junit test and now have no idea about getAll method if I use Pageable, Page and stream() method in my service class.

Here is my getAll method of PostServiceImpl.class

```
@Override
public PostResponse getAllPosts(Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize, String sortBy, String sortDirection) {

    Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name())
            ? Sort.by(sortBy).ascending() : Sort.by(sortBy).descending();

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);
    Page<Post> page = postRepository.findAll(pageable);

    List<Post> posts = page.getContent();

    List<PostDto> content = posts.stream()
            .map(post -> postConverter.mapToDto(post))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    PostResponse postResponse = new PostResponse();
    postResponse.setContent(content);
    postResponse.setPageNo(page.getNumber() + 1);
    postResponse.setPageSize(page.getSize());
    postResponse.setTotalElements(page.getTotalElements());
    postResponse.setTotalPages(page.getTotalPages());
    postResponse.setLast(page.isLast());

    return postResponse;
}
```

PostResponse class

```
public class PostResponse {

  private List<PostDto> content;
  private Integer pageNo;
  private Integer pageSize;
  private Long totalElements;
  private Integer totalPages;
  private Boolean last;
}
```

my getAll method of ServiceTes.class and it seems that I should not write `Page<Post> page = postRepository.findAll(pageable);` in my test case and therefore I do not know how to pass my pageable object in the findAll() method to get the page object then proceed this test case. Please help me and thank you in advance.

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    postDto = new PostDto();
    postDto.setId(1L);
    postDto.setTitle("test title");
    postDto.setDescription("test description");
    postDto.setContent("test content");

    post = new Post();
    post.setId(1L);
    post.setTitle("test title");
    post.setDescription("test description");
    post.setContent("test content");
}

@Test
void givenPostList_whenGetAllPosts_thenReturnPostResponse() {
    int pageNo = 1;
    int pageSize = 3;
    String sortBy = "title";
    String sortDirection = "ASC";

    Post post1 = new Post();
    post1.setId(2L);
    post1.setTitle("test title2");
    post1.setDescription("test description2");
    post1.setContent("test content2");

    List<Post> postList = List.of(post, post1);

    Sort sort = Sort.by(sortBy).ascending();

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);

    BDDMockito.given(postRepository.findAll())
            .willReturn(postList); // not sure if it is necessary

    // do not know what code should be here (page and stream method)

    PostResponse postResponse = postService.getAllPosts(pageNo, pageSize, sortBy, sortDirection);

    Assertions.assertThat(postResponse).isNotNull();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `List<Post>` here

```
 BDDMockito.given(postRepository.findAll()).willReturn(postList);
```

when it is expecting `Page<Post>` here

```
Page<Post> page = postRepository.findAll(pageable);
```

Create a Page Object with that list object and return that. Something like

```
Page<Post> postPage = new PageImpl<>(postList);
BDDMockito.given(postRepository.findAll()).willReturn(postPage);
```

I think you might need to go through the documentation a bit more. I would suggest https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series